# Can't access Custom Dimension in Google Analytics API via R

Tags: r, google-analytics, custom-dimensions

I'm attempting to create reports in `R` using the `googleAnalyticsR` package.  We have 4 custom dimensions defined in `Google Analytics`, and when I try to access 2 of them, no data is retrieved.

In code below, When I use `Dimension1` or `Dimension2`, everything runs smoothly. But if I try `Dimension3` or `Dimension4`, no data is retrieved

```r
library(googleAnalyticsR)
```

```
sampled_data_fetch2 <- google_analytics(ga_id, 
date_range = c("2018-01-01","2018-02-28"), 
metrics = c("sessions"), 
dimensions = c("date", "dimension2"))
```

> 2019-09-09 17:58:16> Downloaded [1000] rows from a total of [8079].

```
sampled_data_fetch2 <- google_analytics(ga_id, 
date_range = c("2018-01-01","2018-02-28"), 
metrics = c("sessions"), 
dimensions = c("date", "dimension4"))
```

> 2019-09-09 17:59:16> Downloaded [0] rows from a total of [].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that `Dimension3` and `Dimension4` are not session-scoped custom dimensions (hence the metrics **sessions** is not returning any results). The output of `ga_custom_vars_list` should confirm this (specifically the **scope** column):

```
cds <- ga_custom_vars_list(
  accountId = account_details$accountId,
  webPropertyId = account_details$webPropertyId
)

head(cds)
```

**Output**:

```
             id accountId webPropertyId                          name index
1 ga:dimension1  418XXXXX UA-XXXXX-5               CD1 NAME (1)     1
2 ga:dimension2  418XXXXX UA-XXXXX-5               CD2 NAME (2)     2
3 ga:dimension3  418XXXXX UA-XXXXX-5               CD3 NAME (3)     3
4 ga:dimension4  418XXXXX UA-XXXXX-5               CD4 NAME (4)     4
5 ga:dimension5  418XXXXX UA-XXXXX-5               CD5 NAME (5)     5
6 ga:dimension6  418XXXXX UA-XXXXX-5               CD6 NAME (6)     6
    scope active             created             updated
1 SESSION   TRUE 2014-02-18 18:42:23 2017-05-25 16:34:20
2 SESSION   TRUE 2015-09-17 21:11:19 2017-05-25 16:34:29
3     HIT   TRUE 2016-06-01 15:12:18 2016-06-01 15:12:18
4     HIT   TRUE 2016-06-01 15:12:27 2017-05-25 16:36:24
5     HIT   TRUE 2016-06-01 15:12:42 2017-05-25 16:36:29
6     HIT   TRUE 2016-06-02 11:27:14 2016-06-02 11:27:14
```

Comment: Dimension1 is Session-Scope, but Dimensions 2-4 are hit-scoped.  And since Dimension 2 works, but 3 & 4 don't, I'm not sure scope is the issue.

Comment: How about the ```created``` date? Maybe custom dimension 3 & 4 were created after the date range you selected?

Comment: That was it.  Both were created in March 2019, if I use dates after that it works.  Thanks so much!